# missing class after compiling protobuf

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers, maven-plugin, grpc-java

I have created a basic proto file with 2 messages and 1 service inside. `Hellorequest` and `Helloresponse` and `Hello` service.

I'm working on a [Maven][1] project in [Visual Studio Code][2].
[1]: https://maven.apache.org/ 
[2]: https://code.visualstudio.com/

I'm using this command to compile:

```
protoc --java_out=DataLink_Parser/backend/src/main/java/com/backend DataLink_Parser/backend/src/main/java/com/backend/HelloService.proto
```

5 files in total are created;
`Hellorequest` and `Helloresponse` java classes are created.
 *Hellorequestorbuild.java*,
*Helloresponseorbuild.java* and last *HelloServiceOuterClass.java* files are created; 
**However I also need class `HelloServiceImplBase`, but it's not created.**

I've tried dependencies and plugins. But the result is the same.

I'm a student learning protobuf, can you help me with this?

Comment: It sounds like you're building the protos but not the gRPC parts.  Check the gRPC documentation.

Comment: protoc --java_out=DataLink_Parser/backend/src/main/java/com/backend --grpc-java_out=DataLink_Parser/backend/src/main/java/com/backend DataLink_Parser/backend/src/main/java/com/backend/HelloService.proto
should I use this command ?

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: it gives this eror.
protoc-gen-grpc-java: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--grpc-java_out: protoc-gen-grpc-java: Plugin failed with status code 1.

Comment: I think u are right. I should run gRPC part. 
protoc --grpc-java_out=DataLink_Parser/backend/src/main/java/com/backend DataLink_Parser/backend/src/main/java/com/backend/HelloService.proto
like that

Comment: I am not a Java developer but I'm familiar with gRPC. As @louis-wasserman suggested, you may want to check out the gRPC [Java](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/) content; it's decent. Using Maven, you do not need to run `protoc` manually but you can incorporate it into a `pom.xml`, see this [example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/pom.xml)

Comment: If you want to use `protoc` standalone, you'll need to install `protoc-gen-grpc-java` and place it in the path so that `protoc` can find it. There are instructions for extracting `protoc-gen-grpc-java` from the Maven artifact [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/compiler/README.md)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I solved the problem in the grpc command above, the missing java class was also created. Thank you for help guys.

Comment: @HüsnüAyaz: Please post your working solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compile the proto file manually, you need to compile it in 2 parts as java_out and grpc-java_out. Like the code below:

```
protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=/home/ayaz/Downloads/protoc-gen-grpc-java-1.56.0-linux-x86_64.exe --grpc-java_out=DataLink_Parser/backend/src/main/java/ --java_out=DataLink_Parser/backend/src/main/java/ DataLink_Parser/backend/src/main/java/com/backend/proto/HelloService.proto
```

And also you need to install [Protoc Gen GRPC Java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-java)

As in the code example above, you need to specify the location of the Protocol Gen GRPC Java that you downloaded.